# Why does OpenCV's cv2.rgbd.warpFrame introduce line pattern in warped image?

Tags: python, opencv, point-clouds

Using OpenCV's cv2.rgbd.warpFrame function, I get an line pattern overlayed over my warped image, see image.

[image: corrupted output image of cv2.rgbd.warpFrame]

Is there a possibilty to get rid of this overlay line pattern?

There are no options in the fuction body to adjust the interpolation, so I am wondering, if this problem can be solved.

Comment: that function works with point clouds. it is only intended for visualization (i.e. debugging) of results "of the Odometry algorithm" (see docs), not for making pretty pictures. this type of artefact will always happen when projecting simple points. in principle, there can be no interpolation.

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz  Thanks for the answer. And yes, my example is based on a point cloud which should be viewed from a different point of view. I will do the projection and interpolation myself, I guess.

Comment: if you project the *point* cloud from a different angle, you'd still just get *points* projected. there is no sensible way to "interpolate" in that case. there is little sense in interpolating this here. at best you can patch this up a little but **in principle** (fundamentally) it is not possible.